# Custom Errors in Validation Engine

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I have 2 text boxes for entering money range 
they should have:

**txtFromAnnualIncome** minimum = 0 maximum = 99999999998

**txtToAnnualIncome** minimum = 1 maximum = 99999999999

I want to check `if txtToAnnualIncome < txtFromAnnualIncome` because i want to have `txtToAnnualIncome  > txtFromAnnualIncome` otherwise the `postback` must not happen.

I am using the `validation engine`. I want to show a custom message to users.

Additionally , I want required and numbers only validation in both textboxes.

How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use simply range validator?

Comment: range validator will help but only partially. Because i want minimum value in `txtToAnnualIncome = Convert.ToInt32(txtFromAnnualIncome)+1` other wise validation error must be thrown

Comment: Well. If you can set range validator's minvalue and maxvalue from code behind, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: You mean using update panel and set the min value of range validator in code.

Comment: Yes. Try to achieve that from code behind.

Comment: Nice Idea but i wanted validation engine to do the work without HTTP AJAX postback.

Comment: Oh ok. So in that case you can achieve through javascript or jquery.